# How to know when I get paid from mining Monero

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mining-pools, cpu-mining, mining, monero-research-lab

I just started to mining Monero, using Claymore v3.8. Via CPU.

With my very weak knowledge of mining, I just want to see a "payment" so can be sure that I am not mining for nothing.

I am using **Monero GUI** for wallet.

**Pool**: `pool.supportxmr.com:5555`

**Average hashrate:** `250 h/z`

And set **-t 4** (in the readme file, said that if you have i7 CPU use this option)

Total hashes are more than **1.5 million** right now.

I also wondering, how can I know that will I be profit from this mining while the computer using electricity, I mean the payment of electricity and gaining Monero from mining via CPU, is it worth it?

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the pool. Many pools will inform you when you stop hashing and when they make payments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some experience I made while dealing with crypto currency:

### Question 1:

Many pools provide you with information about how much Monero you are mining at the moment... In the case of supportxmr [this](https://www.supportxmr.com/#/dashboard) page does the job for you (bottom of the page). You simply enter your wallet address and you can live-track your statistics.

### Question 2:

for more information about how much money you are mining(and losing due to electricity costs) the [cryptocompare](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/xmr) page could be interesting for you. Just enter your average hashrate, electricity costs in you state and your power consumption, the website will take care of everything else and calculate your earnings per day/week/month/year...
Of course you can compare Monero to other crypto currencies as well.

---

Hope I could help :)
Happy mining!

**Edit:** it's more likely to find information about your mining earnings (statistics) on the pools website than the wallet page...